# How to get concrete type values from a collect of interface values without too many duplicate codes in Go

Tags: go, generics

Suppose I have a set of types (e.g. Foo, Bar) that all satisfy an interface called `IProduct`. Also suppose I have a collection of the interface values. Now I want to get a slice of type Foos (`AllFoos` function) or type Bars (`AllBars` function) from the collection of interface values:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IProduct interface {
    GetName() string
    GetId()   int
}

type Product struct {
    name string
    id   int
}

func (p *Product) GetName() string {
    return p.name
}

func (p *Product) GetId() int {
    return p.id
}

const fooId = 1                 // Product Foo's id
const barId = 2                 // Product Bar's id

type Foo struct {
    Product
    x int                       // Foo's internal data
}

type Bar struct {
    Product
    y int                       // Bar's internal data
}

type SameProducts map[int]IProduct
type Products map[int]SameProducts

func AllFoos(data Products) []*Foo {
    objs, ok := data[fooId]
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }

    foos := make([]*Foo, len(objs))

    i := 0
    for _, obj := range objs {
        if obj, ok := obj.(*Foo); ok {
            foos[i] = obj
            i++
        }
    }

    return foos
}

func AllBars(data Products) []*Bar {
    objs, ok := data[barId]
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }

    bars := make([]*Bar, len(objs))

    i := 0
    for _, obj := range objs {
        if obj, ok := obj.(*Bar); ok {
            bars[i] = obj
            i++
        }
    }

    return bars
}

func main() {
    // data has two levels, the first level is a map of product id to
    // products, the second level is a map of individual products
    data := Products{}

    foo := Foo {
        Product: Product {
            name: "foo1",
                id: fooId,
            },
            x: 100,
        }

    foo2 := Foo {
        Product: Product {
            name: "foo2",
                id: fooId,
            },
            x: 101,
    }

    bar := Bar {
        Product: Product {
            name: "bar1",
                id: barId,
            },
            y: 200,
        }

    fooMap := data[fooId]
    if fooMap == nil {
        fooMap = SameProducts{}
    }
    fooMap[foo.x] = &foo
    fooMap[foo2.x] = &foo2
    data[fooId] = fooMap

    barMap := data[barId]
    if barMap == nil {
        barMap = SameProducts{}
    }
    barMap[bar.y] = &bar
    data[barId] = barMap

    // Now list all Foo products or all Bar products:
    
    foos := AllFoos(data)
    for _, obj := range foos {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj)
    }

    bars := AllBars(data)
    for _, obj := range bars {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj)
    }
}

// go run test.go
// &{{foo1 1} 100}
// &{{foo2 1} 101}
// &{{bar1 2} 200}
```

In the project codes, `data` is populated by unmarshaling from a JSON file.

Now the problem. There are duplicated codes in function `AllFoos` and `AllBars`. What if new products like `Baz`, `Quax` added in the future? However I can't figure out how to eliminate the duplicate codes, since I don't know how to pass variable's Type as a function's parameter. I think it is a common problem of static type languages. C++'s template is a way to solve this kind of problem. But what can we do in Go?

Comment: The underlying problem seems to stem from a design problem. You use interface (and don't call them Iwhatever) when you want to _abstract_ away the concrete type but work on common _behavior_ (the interface). Now you seem to be interrested not in the common functionality like GetName (unidiomatic in Go) but the actual type, so just don't store them a IProduct, simply because they _aren't_: An IProduct is anything that supports GetName and GetID and your code doesn't opperat on these Methods.

Comment: Your code seems like a direct translation from some other language and while Go supports interface they might not be used just like in any other language. Now to answer your question. Write polymorphic (aka generic) function that does the type assertion and _please_ start with a len-0-slice and append.

Comment: The code is just a sample, and its purpose is showing what I intend to do. It is not the real code from the project, which is far more complex than this. I would like an answer with concrete description of what to do, not a `generic` one in a couple of words. Thanks.

Comment: As for the "start with a len-0-slice and append" part, since I know the slice's size I believe it is more efficient to allocate the entire buffer once and add each element, than append, which has to re-allocate buffer again and again if the size is not sufficient.

Comment: "since I know the slice's size" you don't , you only know the maximum size. "I believe it is more efficient to allocate the entire buffer once and add each element, than append, which has to re-allocate buffer again and again if the size is not sufficient." Your belive is wrong, especially as you seem to have misunderstood what I said. I did not say "start with a cap 0 slice and append" I said "start with a **len** 0 slice". I thought it would be obvious to allocate enough cap beforehand.

Comment: Yes, I admit I misunderstood what you said. Sure, allocate enough cap beforehand does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple hours looking into Go's generics supporting, I think I get the answer:

```
func AllItems[T IProduct](data Products, id int) []T {
    objs, ok := data[id]
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }

    xs := make([]T, 0, len(objs))

    for _, obj := range objs {
        if x, ok := obj.(T); ok {
            xs = append(xs, x)
        }
    }

    return xs
}

func main() {
    // ... snip ...

    foos1 := AllItems[*Foo](data, fooId)
    for _, obj := range foos1 {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj)
    }

    bars1 := AllItems[*Bar](data, barId)
    for _, obj := range bars1 {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", obj)
    }
}
```

I'm not a generic expert yet, but the codes perfectly solve my problem. The following links: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics, https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics are good start point.

Thanks `Volker` inspire me to look into generic functions.